# Drop datetimes not within certain range from index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
Date                 X
....
2014-01-02 07:00:00 16
2014-01-02 07:15:00 20
2014-01-02 07:30:00 21
2014-01-02 07:45:00 33
2014-01-02 08:00:00 22
....
2014-01-02 23:45:00 0
....
```

1)
So my "Date" Column is a datetime and has values vor every 15min of a day.

What i want is to remove ALL Rows where the time is NOT between 08:00 and 18:00 o'clock.

2)
Some days are missing in the datas...how could i put the missing days in my dataframe and fill them with the value 0 as X.

My approach: Create a new Series between two Dates and set 15min as frequenz and concat my X Column with the new created Series. Is that right?

---

Edit:
Problem for my second Question:

```
#create new full DF without missing dates and reindex
full_range = pandas.date_range(start='2014-01-02', end='2017-11-
14',freq='15min') 
df = df.reindex(full_range,fill_value=0)

df.head()
```

Output:

```
                    Date        X
2014-01-02 00:00:00 1970-01-01  0
2014-01-02 00:15:00 1970-01-01  0
2014-01-02 00:30:00 1970-01-01  0
2014-01-02 00:45:00 1970-01-01  0
2014-01-02 01:00:00 1970-01-01  0
```

That didnt work as you see.

The "Date" Column is not a index btw. i need it as Column in my df

and why did he take "1970-01-01"? 1970 as year makes no sense to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want is to remove ALL Rows where the time is NOT between 08:00
>   and 18:00 o'clock.

Create a mask with `datetime.time`.  Example:

```
from datetime import time

idx = pd.date_range('2014-01-02', freq='15min', periods=10000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.empty(idx.shape[0])}, index=idx)
t1 = time(8); t2 = time(18)
times = df.index.time
mask = (times > t1) & (times < t2)
df = df.loc[mask]
```

> Some days are missing in the data...how could I put the missing days
>   in my DataFrame and fill them with the value 0 as X?

1. Build a date range that doesn't have missing data with [`pd.date_range()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) (see above).
2. Call [`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) on `df` and specify `fill_value=0`.

Answering your questions in comments:

- [`np.empty`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) creates an empty array.  I was just using it to build some "example" data that is basically garbage.  Here `idx.shape` is the shape of your index (length, width), a tuple.  So `np.empty(idx.shape[0])` creates an empty 1d array with the same length as `idx`.
- `times = df.index.time` creates a variable (a NumPy array) called `times`.  `df.index.time` is the time for each element in the index of `df`.  You can explore this yourself by just breaking the code down in pieces and experimenting with it on your own.

Comment: my dataframe says: "Series' object has no attribute 'time'" if i do "times = df.Date.time" , Date is my column and its not an index. i need it as column @Brad Solomon

Comment: Ah.. got it. "times = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).time" works :)

Comment: Try just `times = df.Date.dt.time`

Comment: Hello @Brad Solomon. Me again. at the moment i am trying to implement my second question (Some days are missing in the data...how could I put the missing days in my DataFrame and fill them with the value 0 as X?). I defined as you said a new date range: "newDF = pandas.date_range(start='2014-01-02', end='2017-11-14',freq='15min')  " and then i wrote "new = df.reindex(newDF ,fill_value=0)" but it creates me a new column "Date" and he does not take any value for X. everything is 0. i think the problem is that Date is no index on df. i need Date as column, not as index in df

Comment: did you get the message

Comment: yeah, posting your question as a comment is impossible to read and I have no idea what you're asking